# HMS Core location Kit TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getFusedLocationProviderClient') - Ionic/Capacitor - VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ionic-framework, capacitor, huawei-mobile-services

I'm trying to implement HMS Core location kit into my vue ionic app.

I import HMSLocation and declare it, but when I try to use the `getFusedLocationProviderClient` function I get

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getFusedLocationProviderClient')`

```
import { HMSLocation } from "@hmscore/ionic-native-hms-location/ngx";
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            hmsLocation: null,
            fusedClient: null,
            locationResult: null,
        };
    },
    mounted() {
        this.getLocation();
    },
    methods: {
        async getLocation() {
            this.hmsLocation = new HMSLocation();
            console.log(this.hmsLocation);
            this.fusedClient = this.hmsLocation.getFusedLocationProviderClient();
            this.locationResult = await this.fusedClient.getLastLocation;
        },
    },
    .....
```

`console.log(this.hmsLocation);` returns [image]

node_modules/@hmscore/ionic-native-hms-location/ngx

```js
import { IonicNativePlugin } from '@ionic-native/core';
export declare class HMSLocation extends IonicNativePlugin {
    getGeofenceService(): GeofenceService;
    getGeocoderService(language: string, country?: string): GeocoderService;
    getFusedLocationProviderClient(): FusedLocationService;
    getActivityIdentificationService(): ActivityIdentificationService;
    addListener(event: Events, callback: (data: LocationResult | [] | ActivityConversionResponse | ActivityIdentificationResponse) => void): any;
    disableLogger(): Promise<void>;
    enableLogger(): Promise<void>;
}
export declare class BackgroundManager {
    private constructor();
    static notify(notificationId: number, notification: string): void;
    static makeToast(text: string, duration: number): void;
}
export interface FusedLocationService {
    disableBackgroundLocation(): Promise<void>;
    enableBackgroundLocation(notificationId: number, notification: string): Promise<void>;
    checkLocationSettings(request: LocationSettingsRequest): Promise<LocationSettingsStates>;
    flushLocations(): Promise<void>;
    getLastLocation(): Promise<Location>;
    getLastLocationWithAddress(request: LocationRequest): Promise<HWLocation>;
    getLocationAvailability(): Promise<boolean>;
    getNavigationContextState(requestType: NavigationRequestConstants): Promise<NavigationResult>;
    removeLocationUpdates(requestCode: number, type: RequestType): Promise<boolean>;
    requestLocationUpdates(requestCode: number, request: LocationRequest, callback?: (locationResult: LocationResult) => void): Promise<boolean>;
    requestLocationUpdatesEx(requestCode: number, request: LocationRequest): Promise<boolean>;
    setMockLocation(latLng: LatLng): Promise<void>;
    setMockMode(mode: boolean): Promise<void>;
    setLogConfig(logConfigSettings: LogConfigSettings): Promise<void>;
    getLogConfig(): Promise<LogConfigSettings>;
}
```

Comment: What exactly did you console log? `this.hmsLocation` or `HMSLocation`? I don't know this library, but it seems like your function is a `static method` wich means you call it direcly with `HMSLocation.getFusedLocationProviderClient()`

Comment: Thank you for your response! Doing that gives me

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _hmscore_ionic_native_hms_location_ngx__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.HMSLocation.getFusedLocationProviderClient is not a function`

I've added some of the imported library code to the original post for reference

Comment: I took a look at the documentation and it seems your first attempt was the right one. Can you `console.log(this.hmsLocation)` and look if the class is instantiated?

Comment: Apologies, I see the confusion about the console.log, the screenshot above is the output from `console.log(this.hmsLocation);`

Comment: Is it possible that something overrides your variable `this.hmsLocation`? Can you try to save the `instance` inside a local const?